# How I can link standard C++ libraries with g++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, g++, linker-errors

I just have a simple structure:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../header_files/h.h"
int main(void)
{
    f();
    g();
}
```

**src1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
void f() { std::cout << "f()" << std::endl; };
void g() { std::cout << "g()" << std::endl; };
```

**h.h**

```
void f(); void g();
```

I am trying to (only) compile `main.cpp` and `src1.cpp` with:

```
PS> g++ -c main.cpp src.cpp
```

Then get an executable from the created `.obj` files:

```
PS> g++ main.o src.o -o exec.exe
```

```
.\ss.o:ss.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
\ss.o:ss.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))
\ss.o:ss.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
\ss.o:ss.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::Init()
```

Here I am getting a verbose linker error; that's because I am using iostream library; I just need to tell g++ how to link to this library or any other standard library I want to use. How I can do that?

Actually I can use `g++ main.cpp src1.cpp -o test`, or using any IDE, but I do not need to do this. Just need a way to tell g++ (maybe via command-line args) how to go to the actual definitions. I need to produce the `.exe` file from the generated `obj` files, not something else.

- Windows: x64
- g++ -ver: x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0 (mingw64)
- Not using any IDEs

Comment: *I just need to tell g++ how to link to this library* `PS> gcc main.o src.o -o exec.exe` You are saying g++. Why do you run gcc?

Comment: @S.M. Oh sorry just a typo

Comment: Make sure you don't have this type in your console too, because it would cause the exact problem you describe (though it's not the only way to create that problem).

Comment: Did you try adding the -I flag to your g++ command for the included headers?

Comment: IMHO, prefer not to place paths in `#include` statements.  Files move.  Instead, tell your compiler which directories it should search.